# kotlin native using iOS framework with android studio

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-native

i follow this official tutorial

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html

All works correctly but in Android studio..but how i can turns on autocomplete?
For example the following class "actual.kt"

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile

import platform.UIKit.UIDevice

actual fun platformName(): String {
  return UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() +
          " " +
          UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}
```

cannot provide auto complete. And all other class with this import "platform.UIKit.UIDevice"

Comment: swift it's borderline... UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() +
          " " +
          UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion  is a tipical ios Library...why autocomplete isn't supported?

Comment: see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native-overview.html overview

Comment: sound's better now question?thanks @Moritz

Comment: Yes, a lot better. Thank you for editing your question.

Comment: Kotlin Native is really made for CMake. Only CMake has the plugin anyways. It's likely you can't get autocomplete without it.

Comment: so what i can do @Zoe?

Comment: You use CLion to get the plugin. There might be unofficial plug-ins or better/easier ways, but I assume the plugin is the currently only way to get it

Comment: okay..but i cannot run on simulator Android code...okay for ios use xcode ide...but would like to reduce number of ide in use using Android studio for kt, and launch android app on sim / device.